# How to fetch data from an api and save to mongodb using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, nodes

This is how I have defined my schema

```
const apiSchema = new Schema({
    entries: [{
        API: {
            type: String
        },
        Description: {
            type: String
        },
        Link: {
            type: String
        },
        Category: {
            type: String
        }

    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('api', apiSchema);
```

And here is my controller

```
const Data = require('./models/api');
p.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    request('https://api.publicapis.org/entries', function (error, response, body) {
        var result = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log('body:', result); 
        

result = new Data({
            entries: {
                API: req.body.API,
                Desription: req.body.Desription,
                Link: req.body.Link,
                Category: req.body.Category   
            }
         })
        result.save()
            .then(result => {
                console.log('Entry saved');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        
    });
    
});
```

When I run the server and open compass I find that only the object id in the entries array gets saved. I want all the fields in the entries array to be saved in the database.

Comment: but if I understood correctly, in the code you have given above, you don't save fetched data, is that true? You simply save  the data of the request  object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the fetched data as follows:

1. first import the HTTPS module to send the HTTPS get request
2. create an array to keep buffer chunks
3. When all chunks are completely received, concat these chunks
4. save concatenated data on the DB

```
//test.js controller file
const Data = require('./../database/models/test');
const https = require('https');

module.exports = (req,res)=>{
    let data =[]; //array to keep data chunks
    
    https.get('https://api.publicapis.org/entries', function (response) { //send  request to api
        
  response.on('data', d => {
    data.push(d); //get data as chunk by chunk and push them to array
  }).on('error',e=>{
      console.log(e); //
  });

  response.on('end',()=>{
//when all data chunks are received, 
// concat all buffered chunks and 
//create js object from it
   let fetchedData= JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(data).toString()); 
   console.log(fetchedData);
   let result = new Data({
    entries:fetchedData.entries // fetched data has entries array , that is data that you want to save
});
result.save() //save data to db
    .then(result => {
        console.log('Entry saved');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

    res.send(result);
  })

      
}) };
```

[image: result]

Comment: Is this the conventional way of doing it. Should I always use https module?

Comment: No, because you have used `request` function and this function is the core node function, I have used `https.get method. But you can use the 3rd party library for example **Axios, fetch**, and so on.